# Print array to Divs with show/hide radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, perl

In a perl script I am writing HTML to the screen. 
I have some radio buttons which are showing and hiding divs based on which radio button is clicked. Currently @output is outputting the array all on one line in the div.

How do I output each element in the array on a new line to the div below.

```
@output = split (/\n/, $TESTFILE);
@output2 = split (/\n/, $TESTFILE2);

print "\$(document).ready(function() {\n";
print "    \$(\"div.desc\").hide();\n";
print "    \$(\"input[name\$='visibility']\").click(function() {\n";
print "        var test = \$(this).val();\n";
print "        \$(\"div.desc\").hide();\n";
print "        \$(\"#\" + test).show();\n";
print "    });\n";
print "});\n";

print "<td align=\"left\">Test 1</td><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"visibility\" value=\"1\"></td>\n";
print "<td align=\"left\">Test 2</td><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"visibility\" value=\"2\"></td>\n";


print "<td><div id=\"1\" class=\"desc\"> @output </div>\n";
print "<div id=\"10\" class=\"desc\"> @output2 </div></td>\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably simplest to split your output into parts, like this

```
print qq{<td>\n};

print qq{<div id="1" class="desc">\n};
print "$_<br/>\n" for @output;
print qq{</div>\n};

print qq{<div id="10" class="desc">\n};
print "$_<br/>\n" for @output2;
print qq{</div>\n};

print qq{</td>\n};
```

But I recommend that you use [`HTML::Tiny`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Tiny) instead of building your HTML with literal text. At the least you should use Perl syntax like here documents and different string delimiters to avoid all those escapes. Here's a rewrite of the initial part of your code that does the same thing but in a clearer style

```
my @output  = split /\n/, $TESTFILE;
my @output2 = split /\n/, $TESTFILE2;

print <<'END_TEXT';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='visibility']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });
});
END_TEXT

print qq{<td align="left">Test 1</td><td><input type="radio" name="visibility" value="1"></td>\n};

print qq{<td align="left">Test 2</td><td><input type="radio" name="visibility" value="2"></td>\n};
```

Comment: print "$_<br/>\n" for @output2; Doesn't appear to work for me - it just prints "for (then value of entire array"

Comment: @Jaron787: Then either your code is wrong or you have only one element in your array. What is the output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print Dumper \@output2;`?

Comment: @output2 = qw( Test1 Test2 Test3 Test3 );


$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper \@output2;

Dumper = [ "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test3" ]

Code:

print "<td>\n";
print "<div id=\"1\" class=\"desc\">\n";
print "$_ for @output2\n";
print "</div>\n";

Output = "for Test1 Test2 Test3 Test3 "

Comment: @Jaron787: Your code is wrong: that isn't what I wrote. I have `print "$_<br/>\n" for @output`; you have `print "$_ for @output2\n"`

Comment: print "<td>\n";
print "<div id=\"1\" class=\"desc\">\n";
print "\"$_<br/>\n\" for @output2\n";
print "</div>\n";

Now outputs:

"
" for Test1 Test2 Test3 Test3

Comment: @Jaron787: You're using anything but what I have written. Forget those escapes. You want `print "$_<br/>\n" for @output`

Comment: Ah I understand - Apologies @Borodin I was misreading. This works very well thanks! I will now go ahead and start using HTML::Tiny to clean up the style.

Comment: I have now added a submit button inside one of the divs which reloads the page, is there away to keep the current div displayed onclick of this button <input type="submit" value="Refresh Data" name="submitButton">

Comment: @Jaron787:  Please formulate a new question

Comment: Please see - "Perl Javascipt keep selected div displayed on page refresh button click"